# nested recycler view with dynamic adapter size

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am creating a recycler view like play store in which vertical recycler view contains a horizontal recycler view. But the problem is horizontal list has dynamic number of data.and Inconsistecy detected type error of recycler view occurs.

**Log post**

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 3(offset:3).state:8 android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{4ca8346 VFED..... ........ 0,80-686,393 #7f08014e app:id/vid_rv}, adapter:earn.ads.earningvideos.classes.Category_thumbnail@a083908, layout:android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager@b10e8a1, context:earn.ads.earningvideos.Activities.Home_page@9308787
```

Answer (score 0):

It shows an error because you are accessing that item which does not exist in your inner RecyclerView.

However, you can write below the line in Adapter of Inner RecyclerView.

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
     return mValues.size()==0 ? 0 : mValues.size();
}
```

And add the condition to show a RecyclerView if items are available.
Otherwise, hide your inner RecycelrView if empty.